# About Google Play's "Offers in-app purchases" notation

Tags: android, google-play

I've been learning about Android's in-app purchases (subscriptions) recently.

When does the "Offers in-app purchases" notation on the Play Store come on?

I did a lot of research, but I couldn't find a clear answer.
I'm wondering if the notation will be attached when you upload an APK with billing permission and activate a subscription product.
Or will it work with the alpha version if I upload it?

Thank you very much for your help.